# Reference $(this).parent with class name of 'x'

Tags: jquery, parent

In jquery, how can I refer to the parent of `$(this)` element with a `class` of `'abc'`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(this).parents('.abc');
```

or

```
$(this).parent('.abc');
```

or

```
$(this).closest('.abc');
```

[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) are similar except that `.parent()` only travels up one level in the DOM tree.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple I was overlooking

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>$(this).parent(".abc")</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/parent/